# List of Figures Citation Issue

Tags: table-of-contents, biblatex, floats, captions, citing

I know this has been asked before. However, none of the solutions helped me. I have tried `\notoccite` and that did not work. My issue is that each figure with a citation in the list of figures counts so,

## List of Figures

Figure 1 LoF Caption [1] ..........  1

Figure 2 LoF Caption [2] ..........  2

## Introduction

Sentence with citation [3]

Figure 1: Figure 1 LoF Caption [1]

Figure 2: Figure 2 LoF Caption [2]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx, cite, caption, subcaption, notoccite}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Introduction}

Sentence with a citation \cite{first}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure 1 LoF Caption \cite{second}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Figure 2 LoF Caption \cite{third}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It is important to note that `\autocite` does not work and I am using a *.bib file for my references.

I do not want any citations citations to count in the list of figures.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Why don't you use it like this: `\caption[Figure 1 LoF Caption]{Figure 1 LoF Caption \cite{second}}`?

Comment: I already did that; however, it still doesn't work.

Comment: You have to compile it at least two times to make the ToC refresh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the optional argument of `\caption`.

```
\caption[Figure 1 LoF Caption]{Figure 1 LoF Caption \cite{second}}
```

---

If you are tired of typing things twice, you can put this in your preamble and use `\nocitecaption` instead:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\nocite[1]{%
    {\def\cite##1{\ignorespaces}#1}}
\newcommand\nocitecaption[1]{\caption[\nocite{#1}]{#1}}
```

Comment: @seth I've improved my code to fix the doubled spaces (when putting `\cite` in the middle of the text the spaces on the left would have looked bad (without `\ignorespaces`))