# Multiple Reference List, few with \notice{*}, other only cited items. Possible?

Tags: biblatex

Where it is needed? Thesis preparation.

What do I want to achieve?
Need two separate lists of Reference/Publications.
I have `mine.bib` file for my own publications and `main.bib` which is used to cite References in the thesis.

As [shown here](https://deparkes.co.uk/2015/06/30/latex-thesis-publications-list/), my publications need to be presented with no reference number and all of the `mine.bib` items need to be listed.

But only cited reference need to be listed from `main.bib` in Reference list.

MWE ([from here](https://gist.github.com/moewew/981aae57995f03d450423c77eb94f68c)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
            natbib=true,
            style=ieee,
            citestyle=numeric-comp,
            sorting=none,
            doi=false,
            isbn=false,
            url=true,
            ]{biblatex}

\DeclareRobustCommand\nocite[1]{%
    {\def\cite##1{\ignorespaces}#1}}
\newcommand\nocitecaption[1]{\caption[\nocite{#1}]{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{mine.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{mine.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}[mine.bib] % also tried [mine]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={List of Publications}]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

But it only prints `*` in pdf and throws warning: `Empty bibliography on input line 123`

Why `\DeclareRobustCommand`? Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147937/105582) *to avoid typing things twice*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cite all entries in a bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546871/cite-all-entries-in-a-bib-file)

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to show us more than just those two code snippets. If I combine them into a compilable example document they do what I expect them to: https://gist.github.com/moewew/981aae57995f03d450423c77eb94f68c. Please show us a short example document (including a few sample entries from `mine.bib` and `main.bib`) that reproduces the issue you are asking about.

Comment: @moewe, I tried your MWE is working perfectly. I did the exact same thing in my project, unfortunately, that is not working.I'm trying to get a MWE with `Empty bibliography on input line` Warning...

Comment: Ok, I got where the problem is, don't know the solution though, added MWE.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh The question was edited and is no longer a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\nocite[1]{%
    {\def\cite##1{\ignorespaces}#1}}
```

redefines `\nocite`. That isn't a good idea, especially if you later want to use `\nocite` with its normal definition.

Pick a different name. Since `\DeclareRobustCommand` has no problem overwriting existing names, I threw in a seemingly unnecessary `\newcommand` to make sure the name I'm using is not at already taken.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
            natbib=true,
            style=ieee,
            citestyle=numeric-comp,
            sorting=none,
            doi=false,
            isbn=false,
            url=true,
            ]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\suppresscite}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand\suppresscite[1]{%
    {\def\cite##1{\ignorespaces}#1}}
\newcommand\nocitecaption[1]{\caption[\suppresscite{#1}]{#1}}

\begin{filecontents}{mine.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{mine.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}[mine.bib] % also tried [mine]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={List of Publications}]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```